# Intel transactional synchronization extension (TSX) , my computer support RTM and HLE , i used many ways to confirm this claim , but i can't use them

Tags: transactional-memory

i have tried this snippet of code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<immintrin.h>

using namespace std;


int main(){

unsigned int status = _xbegin();
    if(status == ~(_XBEGIN_STARTED)){
        cout << "Transaction Successful" << endl;
        cout << _xtest() << endl;

        _xend();
    }
    else
        cout << "Transaction Failed" << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

and i have encounter an erro that said Segmentation fault (core dumped) , in the line of _xend() instruction , and the _xtest() instruction return a zero which mean it's not a transaction region
i suggest that my computer tsx featues has been disable
or it depends with operating system knowing that i'm using ubuntu 20.04.1
when i used gdb debugging tool it says (program receive SIGSEGV )